# How can I compare two rows in R data frame by different columns and perform an operation on them?

Tags: r, for-loop

I have some data with a similar structure.

```
test_data <- data.frame(start = c(1,15,17,35),
                         time = c(87, 1, 35, 3),
                         end = c(88,16,52,38))
test_data
  start   time end
1     1     88  87
2    15      1  16
3    17     35  52
4    35      3  38
```

I want to compare the "start" variable with the "end" variable of the *previous* row. If the difference is less then 2 I want to sum them by time, leaving the start from the first row and end of the second row.

So in this test data start in the third observation is 17 and end in the second is 16. The difference is 1 and thus I want to sum them.

I expect such an output

```
    start time end
1     1     88  87
2    15     36  52
3    35      3  38
```

Is there a neat way to do this in R? I tried writing a for loop, but it seems that I am overcomplicating it a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `data.table` with a combination of `shift` and `cumsum`:

```r
library(data.table)
test_data <- data.frame(start = c(1,15,17,35),
                        time = c(87, 1, 35, 3),
                        end = c(88,16,52,38))

setDT(test_data)
test_data[, gid:=ifelse(.I>1 & shift(end) - start < 2, FALSE, TRUE)]
test_data[,.(start=head(start,1), time=sum(time), end=tail(end,1)), by=cumsum(gid)][,-"cumsum"]
#>    start time end
#> 1:     1   87  88
#> 2:    15   36  52
#> 3:    35    3  38
```

<sup>Created on 2021-01-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Note that this would also merge multiple consecutive rows (not just 2) with <2 distance between previous end and current start values.